Passing configuration values to docker container via kubernetes yaml
I have kubernetes yaml defined which uses a docker image to launch container.
Image has ENTRYPOINT defined.
I want to pass java memory configurations(Xmx, Xms) to the container, without interfering with ENTRYPOINT definition.
What is idiomatic way of doing it in kubernetes yaml?

Does this answer your question? kubectl run --command vs -- arguments

Thanks @Phil. Seems I need to use 'args' to supplement ENTRYPOINT.

For JVM options, and memory-related options specifically, you have two straightforward options.
All modern JVMs are aware of the container memory resources ("cgroup memory limits") and are able to set the maximum heap size based on those limits (by default, to half).  If the only options you're trying to set are -Xmx -Xms then you may not need to set them at all; just specify the maximum memory limit for the container and the JVM will figure it out.
containers:
  - image: ...
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 2g # implicitly causes -Xmx1g

If you're using Java 11 or newer (Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17) then the java command supports a JDK_JAVA_OPTS environment variable.  Assuming the image doesn't set it itself, you can inject additional JVM options this way.
containers:
  - image: ...
    env:
      - name: JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS
        value: -Xmx1g -Xms256m

Note that both of these rely on Java-specific mechanisms.  Kubernetes args: gets appended to the image's ENTRYPOINT (and replaces the image's CMD) but this won't help if you need to insert more arguments in the middle of the ENTRYPOINT command.  In many ways environment variables are more flexible than command-line arguments, and I try to lean towards making all options settable by environment variables if possible (in a Spring context, Spring Boot can translate environment variables to Spring properties automatically).
